# Log-Out-Link is nowhere to be found

Tags: discussion

Do not answer "duplicate" - The link is definitely missing - at least not there where others claim it should be:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Did you look here? The log out link is in the "hamburger" StackExchange button at the right-edge of the top menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, found it.